# how to show user name in menu

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a `{{user_name}}` variable in my app.component.ts and I want to use it for displaying the user name which I am getting from local storage after the user logs in.

But this loads only at app start and I want to reload it after the user logs in. When I close and reopen app after log in it works fine and user name displayed. But at first, it shows only "hi" and doesn't show the user name.

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" >
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>
            <p>
            HI! {{user_name}}
        </p></ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>

    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>

      <ion-list >

        <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
          {{p.title}}

        </button>
        <button  menuClose ion-item (click)="logout()" >
          Log Out
        </button>
      </ion-list>

    </ion-content>

  </ion-menu>

  <!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
  <ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

**I know that i can publish an event at user loged in , but how to  reload the menu after receiving the event**

Comment: show the code for getting from localStorage

Comment: This is what state management of variables in Angular does, You need to use observable/Subscribe for this case, as angular is SPA

Comment: Using of **Ionic Events** may help you. Refer to this link https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/util/Events/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a pretty similar case, in my opinion [events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/util/Events/) are the best way to go:

**app.component.ts**

```
   import { ..., Events } from 'ionic-angular'; //First import events

   constructor(
    ...
    public events: Events,
    ...
    ){
        .....
        events.subscribe('user:created', (user) => {

          this.user_name=user.name;

        });

     ...
    }
```

Now your able to change that value anywhere in the app using     `this.events.publish('user:created', user);`

For example:

**login.ts**

```
    import { Your other imports...,Events} from 'ionic-angular';

    constructor(
      ...
      public events: Events,
      ...
      ) {}

     // let's assume you did your login and have an user array which has user.name in it,
     // pass that data like this

     updateUserInfo(user){
      this.events.publish('user:created', user);
     }
```

It will work as expected. Hope it helps...

Comment: yes i have published a event now , but how come i can reload the menu if i publish a event that out of my reach , please leave your valuable suggestion. @Whatatimetobealive

Comment: I m not really sure what do you mean by that? Are you curious about how events work?

Comment: i am sorry , but i know how events works , I just want to know that when a event took place and i have subscribed it. that at that time when that event took place i can catch it and able to show an alert. but instead of that alert only i want that  the menu should reload cause its not showing the users name.
<ion-menu [content]="content" >

Comment: `this.events.publish` will reload the data on Ion menu if you do what I explained on my answer. If you create a stackblitz will be much easier to help.

Comment: thanks a lot You have provided your valuable help after a little addition into the logic . i did it with your help